# Adding tags to Shopify, advanced filter caching?

Tags: caching, tags, shopify

I am adding tags to Shopify products via the [Shopify API](https://docs.shopify.com/api/product).

On the store, I'm using Shopify's [Advanced Group Filtering.](http://supply-electronics.myshopify.com/pages/how-to-enable-advanced-group-filtering) But the interface doesn't correctly filter by tag until I've **manually** saved the product, via the Shopify user interface.

It being Shopify, I can't see a stack trace. I'm assuming the problem is because of caching -- am I right? And since Shopify don't allow the cache to be cleared, is there a save bang method or any method that I can call via the API to cause the cache to be cleared? Or perhaps an after save callback method is run that I'm not triggering over the API call? Any clues welcome.

Comment: Interesting. Do you see your tags when you call up the product in the admin? There are all sorts of issues whereby you can use the API to alter records like orders and fulfillments and the admin does not render the results correctly... it's a moving target for sure.

Comment: Yes, they're all there -- interesting that you've noticed this behaviour with other objects.

Comment: As a quick workaround, I can bulk add a tag to all products then bulk remove it, rather than save products individually, obviously.

Comment: If you touch another attribute but do not change it drastically, perhaps that would trigger Shopify to update the internally cached version it dishes out. Add a space to the description for example, or a variant barcode, or something benign in your case.